# Bootstrap-slider.js are not trigger the setValue change function programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bootstrap-4

I'm using `bootstrap-slider.js`. Everything works fine, but setting a new value with `setValue` does not trigger the `"change"` function.

HTML:

```
<div id="barra-temp">
    <input id="selec-temp" type="text"/>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var barratemp = $("#selec-temp").slider({
        id: "slider-temp",
        min: 1500,
        max: 1850,
        tooltip: 'always',
        tooltip_split: true,
        range: true,
        formatter: function(value) {
            return 'Año: ' + value;
        }
    });
    barratemp.on('change',function(val){
        console.log('It works');
    });
```

CODE TO UPDATE VALUES:

```
$("#selec-temp").slider('setValue',[1550,1552],true);
```

Handlers move to the new position, but the triggerChangeEvent does not trigger.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#functions) for setValue:

- **Parameters**: `newValue`, `triggerSlideEvent`, `triggerChangeEvent`
- **Description**:

> Set a new value for the slider. If optional triggerSlideEvent parameter is true, 'slide' events will be triggered. **If optional triggerChangeEvent parameter is true, 'change' events will be triggered.** This function takes newValue as either a Number, String, Array. If the value is of type String it must be convertable to an integer or it will throw an error.

You are calling `setValue` in the following way:

`$("#selec-temp").slider('setValue',[1550,1552],true);`

This means that `triggerSlideEvent` is `true`, while `triggerChangeEvent` is **`false`** (the default). Thus no change event is triggered. Use the following instead:

> $("#selec-temp").slider('setValue',[1550,1552],true,true);

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it works perfectly, I just missed that!